# Click button on webpage via Applescript - Error

Tags: javascript, applescript

I'm trying to click on a webpage item via `AppleScript` but with no success.

I tried the following code in chrome and safari:

```
execute "document.getElementById('t-strikethrough').click();"
```

and

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('t-strikethrough').click();"
```

In Safari, the first line of code does nothing and the result section of Script Editor says *missing value*. With Chrome, I get the following error:

> Can’t make "document.getElementById('t-strikethrough').click();" into
>   type specifier

This is included inside tell statements to locate app, window and document.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing all of your AppleScript code, it's difficult to see exactly what the problem is. You may want to try setting a variable for the URL like this:

```
set URL of document 1 to "http://www.whatever.com"
do JavaScript "document.getElementById('t-strikethrough').click();" in document 1
```

Check this post to see the full example . [Click Button on Webpage with Applescript/JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40310640/6844169)